# Where does WordPress register default scripts like jQuery?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-register-script

I'm figuring out the ins and outs of WordPress. I know that WordPress sets some default filters and actions in /wp-includes/default-filters.php, but where does it register its scripts like jQuery? We are all able to set jQuery as a dependency or just enqueue it in our themes, but where does WordPress register it?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: why does it matter (unless you just want to understand the internals)?

Comment: Indeed, I just want to understand how WordPress works. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress registers jQuery in the [`wp_default_scripts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_default_scripts/) function, which is found in `wp-includes/script-loader.php`.

```
// jQuery
$scripts->add( 'jquery', false, array( 'jquery-core', 'jquery-migrate' ), '1.11.3' );
$scripts->add( 'jquery-core', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', array(), '1.11.3' );
$scripts->add( 'jquery-migrate', "/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate$suffix.js", array(), '1.2.1' );
```

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!